# How to find the exact column name for the PL/SQL exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a plsql procedure to insert values into a table, but when I run my code, I will get this error:"ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column".
To find out the right point of error I put in the INSERT EXCEPTION  a DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE to identify the exact row where I faced the issue.

```
exception
     when others then
       dbms_output.put_line('sqlcode:sqlerrm' || sqlcode || ':' || sqlerrm);
       dbms_output.put_line('DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE' || BMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
```

This is usefull, becacuse now I know in which line there is the error, but it would be better a way to get the column name.
I looked for online a way and I found out this:[How to get column name for which PL/SQL object population is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109464/how-to-get-column-name-for-which-pl-sql-object-population-is-failing).
Is there another easy way to do that? I would not want to use object in my code.

Comment: Take a look at this short video by Steven Feuerstein (Capture call stack, error code, error stack, error backtrace): [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q33gRojvHIg)

Comment: -- You can catch in a table with errlog
BEGIN
dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'table_name');
END;
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT *
FROM source_table_name
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_table_name ('INSERT') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

Comment: Is this just a one-time error you want to debug? If so, the easiest solution may be to pull out the SQL statement and run it directly in a tool like SQL*Plus or run it through DBMS_SQL, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59762961/409172). Neither approach will provide the column name, but they provide the line and column numbers, which should be good enough for an ad hoc analysis. (Also, I agree that you probably don't want to use my other answer that you linked to. Introducing object-relational code into your system should be a last resort.)